# incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int [in __Driver__.java]

Tags: java

```
class Solution {
public int[] removeDuplicates(int[] nums) {
    int i=0;
    int arr[]= new int[nums.length-1];
    for(int j =1; j<nums.length-1; j++){
        if(nums[i] == nums[j]){
           continue;
        }
        else{
           nums[i]=arr[i];
            
        }
        i++;

    }
    return arr;
}
```

}

**error : Line 7: error: incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int [in **Driver**.java]
int ret = new Solution().removeDuplicates(param_1);
^
**

Comment: so, the problem isn't even in this class? you are aware that an array of ints isn't the same as a single int?

Comment: What is your question? What effort did you do to resolve the problem? Stackoverflow is not a place to just copy and paste error messages.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please read [ask].

Comment: Look at that message: `int ret = new Solution().removeDuplicates(param_1);` - as you can see the code that calls your class expects a single `int` to be returned from `removeDuplicates()` and not an array like you're returning. You might want to re-read the task.

Comment: please add complete code and define what are you trying to achieve

Comment: I doubt your logic is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple mistakes in your code like ->

1. You are returning a integer array from `removeDuplicates()` Method but assigning it to a Integer variable that's why you get a error saying

   **int[]
   cannot be converted to int**
2. You are assigning Zero to `nums[i]=arr[i];` nums array as Array is a non-primitive type so they have a default value of zero.

---

```
public static int[] removeDuplicates(int[] nums) {
      int index = 0;
      int arr[]= new int[nums.length-1];
      Arrays.sort(nums);
      for(int j =1; j<nums.length-1; j++){
          if(nums[j-1] == nums[j]){
             continue;
          } else {
             arr[index++] = nums[j-1];
          }
      }
      return Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, index);
    }
```

---

```
//Driver method
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //You may have converted a string into integers
    int inetgerarray[] = {1,2,2,3,4,1,2,4,5,6,7,6,9,10,2,34,5,6,7,8,4,7};
    int a[] = removeDuplicates(inetgerarray);
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    System.out.println(a[i]);
}
```